# Convert or Import YAML (or similar) to Google Spreadsheet (or CSV)

Tags: csv, yaml

I'm trying to convert YAML-formatted content into a Google Spreadsheet. I'm open to different ideas about how to accomplish what I'm trying to do...

**PROJECT**

FAQ content

**MY REQUIRED DELIVERABLE**

A Google Spreadsheet, with the questions in one column and the answers in the next.

**MY PROBLEM**

I am required to deliver the content in the format specified. This is stupid. I know it's stupid, so let's not get into it here.

I am not going to write paragraphs of text into a spreadsheet. I hate that.

I prefer to compose text in a plain-text editor, using markdown (or similar). (For previous deliverables, I've been able to use a markdown processor with a cobbled-together script to deal with some of their other issues...)

Here's the format I'd like to write in (and have been):

```
Is this a frequently asked question?:
  Yes. People frequently ask this question.

What about this one?:
  Not as much. People don't ask that question very frequently.

Et cetera?:
  And so forth.
```

My idea is to run this through some kind of YAML-to-CSV converter, but I can't find any that seem to work. (Yes, I googled. No, nothing that shows up seems to work.)

**IDEAL SOLUTION**

A combination of tools or whatnot that would allow me to write a little script so I can go from that to a Google Drive spreadsheet in one step.

**OK SOLUTION**

I wouldn't mind if the output was a csv file or an html table and I had to do some copy-and-pasting or something. I also am okay with a slightly different markup format.

**WORTH NOTING**

Both the questions and answers are English content, and use all normal punctuation.

**TRIED UNSUCCESSFULLY**

The first thing I tried was writing it as if it was a table in pandoc's pipe_tables format, but I hated it.

I've also tried the yaml-to-csv converter at http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv but that errors out if the yaml keys have spaces.

Finally, I tried running a sed command to turn my colons and new lines into pipes (or something else) so that I could use pandoc to generate an html table. Nothing about this worked, and I ended up replacing all the "r" characters, which was really stupid...

**WHY NOT JUST COPY-AND-PASTE? (Or -- man up and type into the dang spreadsheet)**

I have a bunch of these to do.

It would make my like a lot better if I could cobble together a script or bunch of tools that would let me convert and upload from a single terminal command.

**tl;dr**

I need to get from a plain-text Key-Value pair format into two columns of a Google Spreadsheet, in as few steps as possible.

Comment: Have you tried writing a script to parse the yaml?

Comment: My coding skills are meager, so I'd would need some guidance on where to even start with this.

Comment: A good place to start is the [YAML website](http://www.yaml.org/).  From the Projects list, you can pick the language you're most comfortable with and then try Googling examples for parsing YAML in that language.

Comment: Well... I started down this path and got Ruby to read in my yaml file. But then the docs for the google-drive-ruby gem are completely impenetrable to me. I have no idea how to just get this crap out into a two column table. This doesn't seem that hard....

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: I got SOMETHING to work!!!
I can't put code in these little comments so I'm adding it as a possible answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved maybe 90% of my problem with some ruby scripting.

```
require 'yaml'
require 'rubypants'

filename = ARGV[0]

yml = YAML.load_file("./#{filename}.yml")

open("#{filename}.html", 'w') do |f|
  f << "<table>"
  yml.each do |q, a|
    q = RubyPants.new(q).to_html
    a = RubyPants.new(a).to_html
    f << "<tr><td>#{q}</td><td>#{a}</td></tr>"
  end
  f << "</table>"
end
```

This at least gets me a basic html table I can copy-and-paste into Google Drive. 
I'm also processing the questions and answers through [RubyPants](https://github.com/jmcnevin/rubypants), which gives me a bit of the markdown features that I like.

Because of the specifics of my issue, I'm going to add some html header and style info and a line to pop the resulting doc open in a browser so I can copy-paste quickly.

I think I'm good, unless someone knows of an EASY way to get the resulting table into Google Docs. (Yes, i know there's an API. Heck if I can figure out how to use it.

----UPDATE----
In case anyone is especially interested, here is my FINAL version.
It does the same thing as above, but adds the rest of the HTML doc, some styling (so that I stay in my preferred display mode -- black background), and opens the file in a browser (that part probably only works on mac, which is fine for me).

```
require 'yaml'
require 'rubypants'

filename = ARGV[0]


yml = YAML.load_file("./#{filename}.yml")

open("#{filename}.html", 'w') do |f|
  f << "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {margin: 20px; font-family: Menlo, Consolas, Arial; color: white; background-color: #222222; }
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      table, td, th { border: 1px solid green; }
      td {vertical-align: top; min-width: 500px; padding: 20px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 32px;}
      .question { color: #dddddd;}
    .answer { color: #efefef;}
    h1 { color: #cccccc; }
    </style></head><body><h1> #{filename}.html </h1><table>"
  yml.each do |q, a|
    q = RubyPants.new(q).to_html
    a = RubyPants.new(a).to_html
    f << "<tr><td class='question'>#{q}</td><td class='answer'>#{a}</td></tr>"
  end
  f << "</table></body></html>"
end

system("open", "#{filename}.html")
```